# Why does clicking a Rails link_to anchor with an href to the server not produce a DomContentLoaded event?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dom, ruby-on-rails-6

Whenever my web page is refreshed, I need to do some JavaScript setup (click handlers, etc.). Where I link to a different page in a JS click handler using `window.location.href=...`, the DomContentLoaded event is fired and the setup is done.

However, when it's a Rails link_to that is handling the click handling, the DomContentLoaded event is *not* fired and the setup is *not* done.

Should I do *all* click handling in JS, or is there a better way?

Comment: link_to can trigger ajax and a turbolinks load, which would not trigger DomContentLoaded. Is this what is happening? What is the full set of arguments for the link_to helper?

Comment: That's probably what's happening. ```render '/reports/report', layout: "application", locals: locals``` Is there another JS event triggered that I could use?

Comment: 'turbolinks:load' would be the event if in fact you are using turbolinks

Comment: Thanks, I moved the click handling setup to the `turbolinks:load` event, and that fixed it. If you'd like to put that in an answer I'll acknowledge it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're using turbolinks, so you need to trigger the js setup of the `turbolinks:load` event.